# Using pandas how I can count the line occurrences in a csv file Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.5

Here is the file input: [File Input](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/9967d711362b275e3486e32536bd2686)

Using the above file, how I can count the line occurences in a csv file using pandas and write in another file with the count appended?  and should remove the rest duplicate lines.

For example:

```
0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno
0   1   -1  -1  1   1   1   -1  no
0   1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  yes
0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno
1   0   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yesno
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yesno
0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno
0   1   -1  -1  1   1   1   -1  no
0   1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  yes
0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno
1   0   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yesno
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yesno
```

**Output should be**

```
0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno 2
0   1   -1  -1  1   1   1   -1  no 2
0   1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  yes 2
0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno 2
1   0   1   1   -1  -1  -1  1   yesno 2
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yesno 2
1   0   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  yesno 2
```

Comment: Please define "count".

Comment: count the line in the complete file and removing the duplicate and write the number of occurrences before of the line of the row of the csv.. I hope you got it.

Comment: @jpp you can check the example I have define in the question

Comment: Is `yesno` / `no` / etc final column included in determining a repeat?

Comment: @jpp Yes it is the final one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
```

Please see this
[How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Once you have this, you can write it to file or do whatever is needed.