# How to get the list of dropped duplicates in DataFrame.drop_duplicates() call?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Python DataFrame with some duplicate items.

Is there an easy (idiomatic) way to get the list of duplicates?

I know about `drop_duplicates()` but it doesn't seem to return what was dropped.

I could develop something by using a hash map to count occurrences, but I want to avoid bloating my code with lots of custom-built functions that perform built-in functionality.

Comment: Possibly already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

A way to get the list of duplicates is with the "duplicated" function. It returns a list of booleans indicating whether the elements are duplicated or not.

One example:

```
from io  import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt1 = StringIO("""card
Amex
Visa
Amex""")
monthly_df = pd.read_csv(txt1)

print(monthly_df.duplicated())

print(monthly_df[monthly_df.duplicated()])
```

The output of this code is:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
   card
2  Amex
```

So I think that the piece of code that you are looking for is something like:

```
monthly_df[monthly_df.duplicated()]
```