# How can I choose the multiple(like 2 or 5) frequent rows that the values of each column are exactly the same in python?

Tags: python, pandas, count

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
       A         B          C          
0      1         2          a
1      6         5          c
2      5         4          b 
3      2         5          d 
4      4         9          q
5      1         2          a  
6      5         4          b
7      1         2          a
8      1         4          c
```

I want to find the 2 most frequent rows(every value in the row are exactly the same) and the corresponding frequency.  In this example, the row would be 1 , 2, a and 5,4,b. The frequency is 3 and 2.

I know how to find the most frequent row that I can use mode function. I also know that I can use Counter to select multiple frequent values in one column. How can I choose the multiple(like 2 or 5) frequent rows that the values of each column are exactly the same in python?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### collections.Counter

You can use `collections.Counter` with tuples derived from your dataframe. The idea is to convert each dataframe row to a `tuple`, so that it is hashable, before feeding to `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(map(tuple, df.values))
res = c.most_common(2)

print(res)

[((1, 2, 'a'), 3), ((5, 4, 'b'), 2)]
```

#### GroupBy + size

For a Pandas-based approach, you can use `GroupBy` with `size`, then sort and select the top 2:

```
res = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()\
        .sort_values(ascending=False)\
        .head(2)

print(res)

A  B  C
1  2  a    3
5  4  b    2
dtype: int64
```

As per the other answers, `pd.Series.nlargest` is an efficient alternative to sorting and then extracting the first *n* elements.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try with `groupby`  and `nlargest()` following [similar approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35584675/5916727):

```
print(df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().nlargest(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also `agg` and `count`

```
s = df.agg(tuple,1)
s = s.groupby(s).count()

(1, 2, a)    3
(1, 4, c)    1
(2, 5, d)    1
(4, 9, q)    1
(5, 4, b)    2
(6, 5, c)    1
dtype: int64
```

Then, for instance

```
s.nlargest(2)

(1, 2, a)    3
(5, 4, b)    2
```