# Find duplicated rows, multiply a certain column by number of duplicates, drop duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe of about 70000 rows, and 4500 of them are duplicates of an original. The columns are a mix of string columns and number columns. The column I'm interested in is the `value` column. I'd like to look through the entire dataframe to find rows that are completely identical, count the number of duplicated rows per row (inclusive of the original), and multiply the `value` in that row by the number of duplicates.

I'm not really sure how to go about this from the start, but I've tried using df[df.duplicated(keep = False)] to obtain a dataframe `df1` of duplicated rows (inclusive of original rows). I appended a column of Trues to the end of `df1`. I tried to use .groupby with a combination of columns to sum up the number of Trues but the result was unable to capture true number of duplicates (i obtained about 3600 unique duplicated rows in this case).

Here's my actual code:

```
duplicate_bool = df.duplicated(keep = False)
df['duplicate_bool'] = duplicate_bool
df1= df[duplicate_bool]
f = {'duplicate_bool':'sum'}
df2= df1.groupby(['Date', 'Exporter', 'Buyer', \
                       'Commodity Description', 'Partner Code', \
                       'Quantity', 'Price per MT'], as_index = False).agg(f)
```

My idea here was to obtain a separate dataframe `df2` with no duplicates, and i could multiply the entry in the `value` column inside with the number stored in the summed `duplicate_bool` column. Then I'd simply append `df2` to my original dataframe after removing all the duplicates identified by .duplicated.

However, if I use groupby with all columns I get an empty dataframe. If I don't use all the columns, I don't get the true number of duplicates and i wont be able to append it in any way.

I think I'd like a better way to do this since i'm confusing myself.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking to count the occurrences of each duplicate?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I want to count the occurrences of each duplicate, then remove the duplicates and multiply a value in the row by the number of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is nothing more of figuring out how to get a count of the occurrences of each unique row. If a row occurs only once, this number is one. If it occurs more often, it will be > 1. This count you can then use to multiply, filter, etc.

This nice one-liner (taken from [How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)) creates an extra column with the number of occurrences of each row:

`df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'dup_count'})`.

To then calculate the true value of each row:

`df['total_value'] = df['value'] * df['dup_count']`

And to filter we can use the `dup_count` column to remove all duplicate rows:

`dff = df[df['dup_count'] == 1]`

Comment: Hey thanks once again. I’m having some trouble with that one -liner (I’ve tried it earlier) and it told me something about my list index being out of range... I literally replaced df wih the name of my dataframe and ran it though

Comment: Can you maybe provide some sample data?

Comment: Sorry man, not at the computer anymore. I’ll get back to you tomorrow about this. Thanks for trying and I hope to hear from you tomorrow.