# How to group a dataframe by column and get number of repeating lines?

Tags: pandas

I want to get a number of sales for each day from my dataframe

I tried to call just `df.groupby(['sale_date']).count()` but it doesn't compute the numbers.

Source dataframe looks like:

```
sale_date, borough, building_class, ...
2003-01-01, ...
2003-01-01, ...
2003-01-02, ...
```

And I want to have a new dataframe which will look like this:

```
sale_date, number_sales
2003-01-01, 2
2003-01-02, 1
```

Comment: `df.groupby('sale_date').borough.count()` ?

Comment: You can use value_counts, df.sale_date.value_counts()

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) will help?

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby all the columns in the dataframe, then take the `size` to get the number of counts.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['a']],
              columns=['A'])

df['B'] = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']
print(df) 
#    A  B
# 0  a  b
# 1  a  b
# 2  a  b
# 3  b  c
# 4  b  a
# 5  a  c

df = df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size().reset_index()

df.rename(columns = {0: 'number_sales'}, inplace = True)

print(df)

   A  B  number_sales
0  a  b             3
1  a  c             1
2  b  a             1
3  b  c             1
```