# Equivalent of pandas.Series.value_counts for pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count how many times tuples of data appear in a pandas DataFrame. For example, suppose my data looks like this:

```
    a  b
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   1  0
3   1  1
4   1  1
```

I would like to get a "number of times each row occurs" output like this:

```
(0,0)    2
(1,0)    1
(1,1)    2
dtype: int64
```

However, the closest thing that I know how to do is to do some arithmetic that merges the two columns into a series and then call `value_counts` on the series:

```
>>> (df['a'] * 10 + df['b']).value_counts()
 0     2
10     1
11     2
dtype: int64
```

I don't want to have to manually merge the columns to get these counts. But `DataFrame` doesn't seem to have a `value_counts` method:

```
>>> df.value_counts()
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Is there an easy way to get the row count information from a dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) --- should be the answer you need (group by all columns and count number of items in each group).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the columns into a single tuple column via `.apply(tuple, 1)` and then count that:

```
>>> df.apply(tuple, 1).value_counts()

(0, 0)    2
(1, 0)    1
(1, 1)    2
dtype: int64
```