# Sorting a dataframe by month and grouping by a count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Tags dataframe that has 2 columns "Date" & "Tag", there is multiple same dates and multiple of the same tag. I need to sort the table so that it shows a unique date alongside a unique tag and the count of how many times that tag occurred that month. Any ideas how I could do this? Please see below a screenshot of the current table.

[image: Tags Table]

Comment: Try `pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(tags['Date']), tags['Name'])`

Comment: Please post samples in text format not in image format, kindly do edit post and let us know then.

Comment: You could take some inspiration from the answers here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe , in particular this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/41269427/11989080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Nov','Nov','Dec'],
                   'Name':[1,2,1]}) # sample dataframe
```

If you want to have the `count` of the unique `Names` by `Date` you can do this

```
df.groupby('Date')['Name'].nunique()
    Date
Dec    1
Nov    2
```

If you want to add this information as a new column in your dataframe you can do this

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('Date')['Name'].transform('nunique')
      Date  Name  count
0  Nov     1      2
1  Nov     2      2
2  Dec     1      1
```