# Pandas - count of all unique column combinations including rows with NONE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
      x_1   x_2     x_3     x_4        x_5    ID
0     159   xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10
1     159   xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10
2     159   xyz  883nne2  28h93        NaN    10
3     159   xyz  94mmm4k    NaN      heavy    15
4     159   xyz  94mmm4k    NaN      heavy    15
3     354   abc  94mmm4k    NaN        NaN     3
```

I would like to capture all unique possibilities based on the ID column and create a count column, with the output being:

```
      x_1          x_2     x_3     x_4        x_5    ID  Count
0     159          xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz    10      2  
1     159          xyz  883nne2  28h93        NaN    10      1
2     159          xyz  94mmm4k    NaN      heavy    15      2
3     354          abc  94mmm4k    NaN        NaN     3      1
```

Again, the end goal to take all possible combinations found in x_1 through x_5 column and get a count based on the ID column

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the nan value because they will be excluded. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby). You can try this:

```
df.fillna('').groupby(df.columns.to_list()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

   x_1  x_2      x_3    x_4        x_5  ID  count
0  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93             10      1
1  159  xyz  883nne2  28h93  xx_lightz  10      2
2  159  xyz  94mmm4k             heavy  15      2
3  354  abc  94mmm4k                     3      1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Instead of -1 can it be set to an empty string?

Comment: Perfect, going to try this out tomorrow in the AM. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi Luigigi, thank you this did what I was looking for!