# How to aggregate and then expand frequency values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe of the following shape:

```
import pandas as pd
l = []

l.append({"t":'a', 'w': 'x'})
l.append({"t":'a', 'w': 'x'})
l.append({"t":'a', 'w': 'y'})
l.append({"t":'b', 'w': 'y'})
l.append({"t":'b', 'w': 'y'})
l.append({"t":'b', 'w': 'z'})
l.append({"t":'b', 'w': 'y'})
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

I want to first aggregate based on t colmun and then expand to show each items frequency in w column. In other words I want the following result:

```
   t  w  freq
0  a  x     2
1  a  y     1
2  b  y     3
3  b  z     1
```

How is this possible? I tried so many different ways with no result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dfLet's try `groupby().value_counts()`:

```
df.groupby(['t'])['w'].value_counts().reset_index(name='freq')
```

Alse, `groupby().size()`:

```
df.groupby(['t','w']).size().reset_index(name='freq')
```

Output:

```
   t  w  freq
0  a  x     2
1  a  y     1
2  b  y     3
3  b  z     1
```

Answer (score 3):

`value_counts` now accept two columns

```
df.value_counts(['t','w'])
Out[6]: 
t  w
b  y    3
a  x    2
b  z    1
a  y    1
dtype: int64
```