# Find the most common combination in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I am using pandas and I trying to figure out a way that I can get the most common combinations of products people use in my datafile.

Supposing that each column of the next three AA, BB and CC represents a completely different product and the 0 value means that I don't use this product and the 1 that I do use it. Also, each row represents and a completely different buyer.

For example, the most common combination in my example is the products AA and CC because I have three people that use them as you can see in lines 1,4,5.

My result I would like to be something like 'The most common combination is the products AA and CC which are used by 3 people'.

I hope I have explained to you better this time

Below is an example of my DataFrame:

```
AA  | BB  | CC
_______________
1   | 0   |  1
0   | 0   |  1
0   | 1   |  0
1   | 0   |  1
1   | 0   |  1
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind why your expected result AA CC is considered best?  Also, Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you very much, but I had tried the same as your suggestion, but as I explained in my question I don't want to get the sum or something similar I need to get the names of the columns each customer has 1 in the dataframe

Comment: @GeoP It's not a sum, it's a count of rows. How are you supposed to find the most common rows if you don't count them? That said, it is only the first step. I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you [count duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35584085/4518341), you just need to do a bit of work to get the corresponding labels.

Here's how I would do it, though I'm not very familiar with Pandas so there's probably a better way. Firstly, the df should be boolean.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AA': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    'BB': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'CC': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]}
    ).astype(bool)

# Count duplicate rows
counts = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
# Get most common rows
maxima = counts[counts==counts.max()]
for combination, count in maxima.iteritems():
    # Select matching labels
    labels = df.columns[list(combination)]
    print(*labels, count)
```

Output:

```
AA CC 3
```

---

Partial results:

```
>>> counts
AA     BB     CC   
False  False  True     1
       True   False    1
True   False  True     3
dtype: int64

>>> maxima
AA    BB     CC  
True  False  True    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out almost the solution to my question before your response, but you [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea)  were partially correct, so thank you.

First, I had to go through the whole dataframe, row by row, looking for the one value each time like this and get the product name that I have 1.

```
combination = df.apply(lambda row: row[row == 1].index.tolist(), axis=1)
combination = pd.DataFrame(combination)
```

After that, I created a new column with the names of the products each user use which I had to separate likes.

```
df['Products'] = [' , '.join(map(str, l)) for l in combination[0]]
```

Then I just used your code and I get exactly what I wanted

Comment: If you're going to pick out the names first, why use all of my code after? You could just do `counts = df.groupby('Products').size()` but then get `maxima` the same way.

Comment: BTW, why do you do `combination = pd.DataFrame(combination)` only to do `combination[0]` right after?

Comment: BTW, use the vectorized string methods: `df['Products'] = combination[0].str.join(' , ')`

Comment: I didn't think about your last suggestion at all but I have already changed because it is better, I will also check and your first suggestion