# How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe where the order of the column values is not important?

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if we can extend the logic of [How to count duplicate rows in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584085/how-to-count-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe), so that we also consider rows which have similar values on the columns with other rows, but the values are unordered.

Imagine a dataframe like this:

```
    fruit1  fruit2
0   apple   banana
1   cherry  orange
3   apple   banana
4   banana  apple
```

we want to produce an output like this:

```
    fruit1  fruit2  occurences
0   apple   banana  3
1   cherry  orange  1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly re-assign the `np.sort` values like so, then use `value_counts()`:

```
import numpy as np

df.loc[:] = np.sort(df, axis=1)
out = df.value_counts().reset_index(name='occurences')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   fruit1  fruit2  occurences
0   apple  banana           3
1  cherry  orange           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.sort` along `axis=1` to sort the values in your rows.

Then it's just the regular `groupby.size()`:

```
import numpy as np

fruit_cols = ['fruit1','fruit2']
df_sort = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,axis=1),columns=fruit_cols)
df_sort.groupby(fruit_cols,as_index=False).size()
```

prints:

```
   fruit1  fruit2  size
0   apple  banana     3
1  cherry  orange     1
```